# Infinite drag perfect-scrollbar issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, perfect-scrollbar

I came across a unique situation while applying [perfect-scrollbar](https://utatti.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/) to a container whose `height` is applied dynamically.

The scroll goes down the container even after reaching the end and while `wheelPropagation` set to `false`.

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ejrapndq/)

Note: This issue can be reproduced only in Firefox browser. It works perfectly in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs if the 'Dynamic height' calculated has some decimal points in the `px` value. Eg: `250.65px`

Round off the value to the nearest integer and the issue won't occur in Firefox browser.

The original issue -> [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60amkhe4/)

The fixed one -> [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7Lnr4yg/2/)